# Sobre o arquivo htaccess

Tags: php, aplicação-web, apache, htaccess

No momento do comissionamento dos dados de servidores APACHE com PHP, o que devemos fazer em relação ao arquivo “.htacess”?

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi bem a duvida, mas primeiro corrija o nome para de `.htacess` para `.htaccess` (duas letras `c` e duas letras `s`), deve funcionar.

O `.htaccess` não tem ligação direta e nem é necessário para que consiga "consumir" os dados, Apache é o servidor, PHP é a linguagem dinâmica do **lado servidor** (chamamos de `server-side`).

O mysql **é outro servidor** que é acessado pelas APIs do PHP.

E o `.htaccess` é algo que se usa para ajustar algumas configurações do Apache e de módulos do Apache, como por exemplo:

- Criar URLs customizadas (se tiver habilitado o `mod_rewrite`)
- Controlar os headers das páginas, como por exemplo o uso de cache (se tiver habilitado módulo `mod_headers`)
- Controlar permissões de diretório

Fora uma série de outros módulos como no tutorial da Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: @JúlioCésarRamos se a resposta do gabarito for algo como "reescrever urls", então a prova esta errada (acredite já vi coisas bizarras assim), .htaccess é para configurar modulos do Apache do qual permitam o contexto do .htaccess (tem módulo do Apache que só pode ser configurado no `httpd.conf`, ou seja exige parte do administrador do servidor), quem reescreve as URLs é módulo "mod_rewrite", o .htaccess apenas permite configura-lo.